# To check if IEnumerable is not null before checking for Any() in c#

Tags: c#

I was in a situation where I got a statement that checks if the collection is actually null before going into checking for Any() (having any elements at all) .

```
if(myIEnumerableCollection?.Any() ?? false)
   {
      // do this logic 
   }
```

I know that myIEnumerableCollection is checked and if it is null(c# 6 syntax, correct me if I am wrong)  , the argument null exception is thrown . I wanted to get an understanding of this statement as what it is evaluating , as the syntax is a bit confusing to read.

My understanding is that :

1. Check the collection for not null and should be false.
2. Chained with Any() for any elements in the sequence if the first condition is not
   true(myIEnumerableCollection? not null) .
3. If the expression myIEnumerableCollection?.Any() is true ( this is where I am
   getting confused how is it evaluating to true )  go inside the if logic
   else evaluate to false.

Any links or references or explanation will help. I am getting a bit rusty and it might look like a very basic question, my concern was with the readability of the expression.

Thank you.

Comment: propably a usefull link: https://dev.to/pushpk/using-null-conditional-and-coalescing-operators-in-c-1186

Comment: `myIEnumerableCollection?.Any()` means, if `myIEnumerableCollection` is null, the rest properties-getting (don't quite know how to call this; in this case, `.Any()`) will not be evaluated, instead returns null, hence `null ?? false`. If `myIEnumerableCollection` is not null, then `.Any()` will actually be called and get a boolean.

Comment: If other words, `myIEnumerableCollection?.Any()` can translate to `if (myIEnumerableCollection != null) { myIEnumerableCollection.Any(); } else { null; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?.` or [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) syntax skips evaluation of the rest of the expression and evaluates null if the left side value is null. So `myIEnumerableCollection?.Any()` will give a type of `bool?` i.e. either null, true, or false. The `?? false`, or [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator), convert the null-case to false.